# One Div animation after another using deferred object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred, deferred

Animate the Div after the previous Div animation has completed using `deferred object`. This simple method works with the two functions `f1` and `f2`, however when I introduce `f3` it fails.

Is there a better way I can achieve this using the deferred object?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j0bgzjvd/

```js
var deferred = $.Deferred();

function animationAgent(element, prevElement) {
  $(prevElement).promise().done( function () {
    return $(element).css("display", "block").animate({width:360},2000, "linear")
  });
}

function f1() {
  animationAgent("#div1"); 
} 

function f2() {
  animationAgent("#div2", "#div1"); 
} 

function f3() {
  animationAgent("#div3", "#div2"); 
}

deferred.resolve();
deferred.done( [ f1, f2, f3 ] );
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px; 
  height: 200px; 
  background-color: red; 
  margin-bottom: 10px; 
  display: none;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
```

Comment: Can you add a snippet or bin with this problem? Any errors in the `console`?

Comment: Please see the JSFiddle updated in the post. No errors are present in the console. I would like the divs to animate one after the other in harmony, however as you can see function 3 results in a disturbance in the sequence of animations. Taking out f3 allows f1 and f2 to animate in sequence - @MoshFeu

Comment: Check out the answer below might help. @jcoulston2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find it simpler to :

- make `animationAgent()` into a simple, promise-returning worker function that knows only about the element it animates, and nothing about the sequence in which it is to be used (ie omit `prevElement`),
- arrange for functions `f1()`, `f2()` and `f3()`, to return the promise returned to them by `animationAgent()`.

Then you have the basis for building a reliable animation sequence.

```
function animationAgent(element) {
    return $(element).css("display", "block").animate({width:360}, 2000, "linear").promise();
}
function f1() {
    return animationAgent("#div1"); 
} 
function f2() {
    return animationAgent("#div2"); 
} 
function f3() {
    return animationAgent("#div3"); 
}

f1().then(f2).then(f3);
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/j0bgzjvd/1/)**

Alternatively, construct the .then chain mechanistically from an array of function references :

```
function animationAgent(element) {
    return $(element).css("display", "block").animate({width:360}, 2000, "linear").promise();
}
function f1() {
    return animationAgent("#div1"); 
} 
function f2() {
    return animationAgent("#div2"); 
} 
function f3() {
    return animationAgent("#div3"); 
}

[f1, f2, f3].reduce(function(promise, fn) {
    return promise.then(function() {
        return fn();
    });
}, $.when());
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/j0bgzjvd/2/)**

Or, as the three animations are identical, you can avoid the need for individual functions by constructing the .then chain from an array of element selectors and calling `animationAgent()` directly :

```
function animationAgent(element) {
    return $(element).css("display", "block").animate({width:360}, 2000, "linear").promise();
}

['#div1', '#div2', '#div3'].reduce(function(promise, selector) {
    return promise.then(function() {
        return animationAgent(selector);
    });
}, $.when());
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/j0bgzjvd/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Ever thought about using callbacks in the animation function?

Here's an example with fadeOut: https://jsfiddle.net/0r7e2wco/

```
fadeOutInTurn([
    $("#div1"),
    $("#div2"),
    $("#div3"),
    $("#div4"),
]);

//Fades out elements one after another
function fadeOutInTurn(elements) {
    var x = 0;
    function animate() {
        $(elements[x]).fadeOut(3000, function() {
            if(x < elements.length - 1) {
                x++;
                animate();
            }
        });
    }
    animate();
}
```

Comment: "Is there a better way I can achieve this?" I assumed he wanted to know better ways to animate elements one after another.

Comment: If he wants to use a deffered object he should use notify() and progress() instead of resolve() and done(), this way a deffered object can be used a unlimited amount of times ^^ But I don't understand why anyone would  use a deffered pattern for animating some elements in turn...

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, more specifically the deferred object, my logic was to use the promise method to allow the sequence of functions to initiate one after the other. The reason being, this animation is part of a more complex process with click stages and I wanted to try this method to allow an elegant solution with regards to certain conditions @seahorsepip

Answer (score 0):

not sure but i think this is what you want.

working example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j0bgzjvd/4/)

I think you are hoping `deferred.done()` will execute `f1, f2, f3` one after other well it does that. but it does not wait for the animations called inside these functions to terminate before calling the next function.

try logging the function calls on console using `console.log()` and you will know.

here is the updated javascript code -

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();
var lock = 1;

function animationAgent(element, id, prevElement) {
  var interval;
  var flag = 0;
  if (id != lock) {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      if (id == lock) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        animationAgent(element, id, prevElement);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }else{
    $(prevElement).promise().done(function() {
      lock++;
      return $(element).css("display", "block").animate({
        width: 360
      }, 2000, "linear");
    });
  }
}

function f1() {
  return animationAgent("#div1", 1);
}

function f2() {
  return animationAgent("#div2", 2, "#div1");
}

function f3() {
  return animationAgent("#div3", 3, "#div2");
}

deferred.resolve();
deferred.done([f1, f2, f3]);
```